# Regex find all money related value in a long string

Tags: python, regex, extract, currency

I am trying to extract money-related value from a long string.
I can match the following format using `(?:cad|[$]|usd)\s*\d+?`

```
$1000
cad 1000 
usd 1000
```

1. I have trouble with the one with 1000 separators, like $1,000.
2. I tried to add `(\.\d+)` to account for the optional digit and it is not working.
3. If I try to account for another convention like 1000$ and 1000cad, is it better to do a separate regex for the reversed symbols and amount?

test1 = 'Today is 23, I will pay you $10,000.78 today by 7'

expect = $10,000.78

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an alternation `|` to match both formats and use whitespace boundaries to prevent partial matches.

For matching the money you can use a character class `[\d,.]+` to repeat matching a digit, comma or dot if you know that the money is always in the expected format and will never be for example `$,,`

```
(?<!\S)(?:(?:cad|[$]|usd) ?[\d,.]+|[\d.,]+(?:cad|[$]|usd))(?!\S)
```

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/9zDMut/1).

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex tester to try stuff out.  One good one is https://regex101.com/.

You need to use a character class `[]` like so:

`(?:cad|[$]|usd)\s*[\d,.]+`

... and get rid of the `?` which tells the regex to stop after the first digit.

If you want to check for optional stuff afterward, add an optional grouping:

`(?:cad|[$]|usd)\s*[\d,.]+(?:cad|usd|\$)?`

... in this case, the trailing `?` means "optional".  Additionally, I recommend using the "i" (case insensitive) regex switch.

Foul